# extract cellulose from CMC using cuoxam reagent (schweizer's reagent)

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism, reagents

Good day, I am new in the field of chemestry. My question is, if it is possible to reverse or extract (I am not very sure how to say it), cellulose from carboxymethyl cellulose (CMC) by the use of schweizer's reagent. I read that this reagent is capable to "regenerate" cellulose from a different sources, but unfortunately I havent found any paper that can support this idea.
I want to thank in advance for your time and help.

Comment: Nobody thinks of regenerating cellulose from carboxymethyl cellulose. it is not worth while. Cellulose is a cheap product. Carboxymethyl cellulose is a rather expensive product. So why spend much money from an expensive substance to be converted in a cheap derivate ?

Comment: The reason, is because in the laboratory where I am working, we have a huge amount of CMC, that nobody use and we have the materials to do the cuoxan reagent. That is the main reason